# Terminal, MySQL how to quit insert mode?

Tags: mysql, terminal

Entering a mysql command in terminal and hitting return gives a new line.

[image]

But sometimes when I make mistake I cannot quit this mode even by closing the statement with semicolon. Ctrl + c quits mysql. How can I quit just insertion mode?

Comment: I have this problem right now. The terminal looks like this:create user '***'@'localhost identified by '***';
    '> ;
    '>

Answer (score 0):

you have to close the SQL Statement with ';' e.g: SELECT * FROM Table;

When you do so and press ENTER the query is executed.

Comment: That is Really strange..... What kind of OS/terminal etc. are you using? And which version of MySQL?

Comment: OS X/native terminal, MAMP, MySQL 5.5.
I tried to reproduce conditions on which it happens, but couldn't. Will update the post as I'll get it again..